# How to upload image to server with Get method in nsurl connection in ios?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

i am trying to upload image with get method.
and i am getting error  [Can not Parse response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820224/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1017-cannot-parse-response)

in the solution i found that set http method"POST"

but i am using GET method.

and i am not able to upload an image.
here is my sample code i am using

```
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:pngData]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profile_image\"; filename=\"chat.png\"\r\n", @"profile_image"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

// Prifile image is my key

and i also have other fields to insert.

can you please help me find out what is wrong with code or setup?

Comment: do you want to do that only using NSURLcollection or want to try other option ?

Comment: thanks for response.i can try options also