# Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1017 "cannot parse response" Firebase Storage iOS

Tags: swift, objective-c, firebase, firebase-storage

I am uploading files to FirebaseStorage and i am getting this error on iOS :

```
Task <24E18897-20B7-45FD-9621-85FF09DC6326>.<1> finished with error [-1017] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1017 "cannot parse response" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-1, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=BackgroundUploadTask <24E18897-20B7-45FD-9621-85FF09DC6326>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "BackgroundUploadTask <24E18897-20B7-45FD-9621-85FF09DC6326>.<1>",
    "LocalUploadTask <24E18897-20B7-45FD-9621-85FF09DC6326>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=cannot parse response, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mybucket/o/user%2FNyq7dMqe1kcAZ77R1YwH5fsAkV83%2Fcontent%2F43aa2d41-7a19-11ec-bd39-85fcd9d025?uploadType=resumable&name=user%2FNqe1kcAZ77R1YwH5fsAkV83%2Fcontent%2F43aa2d41-7a19-11ec-bd39-8508fcd025&upload_id=ADPycdv0-OYZPx3zAGzLrn25ZdI9srgkgABHGKb_1fCqUO7AAPHsZTkz_iVX1NfuYQsn0LHgCCiOsSzhLiP4Ho7VynSf_ceJJw&upload_protocol=resumable, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mybucket/o/user%2FNyqMqe1kcAZ77R1YwH5fsAkV83%2Fcontent%2F43aa2d41-7a19-11ec-bd39-8508fcd9d025?uploadType=resumable&name=user%2FNyq7dMqe1kcAZ77R1YwH5V83%2Fcontent%2F432d41-7a19-11ec-bd39-8508f9d025&upload_id=ADPycdv0-OYZPx3zAGzLrn25ZdI9srgkgABHGKb_1fCqUO7AAPHsZTkz_iVX1NfuYQsn0LHgCCiOsSzhLiP4Ho7VynSf_ceJJw&upload_protocol=resumable}
GTMSessionFetcher invoking fetch callbacks, data (null), error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1017 "cannot parse response" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-1, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=BackgroundUploadTask <24E18897-20B7-45FD-9621-85FF09DC6326>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "BackgroundUploadTask <24E18897-20B7-45FD-9621-85FF09DC6326>.<1>",
    "LocalUploadTask <24E18897-20B7-45FD-9621-85FF09DC6326>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=cannot parse response, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mybucket/o/users%2FNyq7dMqe1kcAZ77R1YwH5fsAkV83%2Fcontent%2F43aa2d41-7a19-11ec-bd39-8508fcd9d025?uploadType=resumable&name=users%2FNyq7dMqe1kcAZ77R1YwH5fsAkV83%2Fposts%2F43aa2d41-7a19-11ec-bd39-8508fcd9d025s&upload_id=ADPycdv0-OYZPx3zAGzLrn25ZdI9srgkgABHGKb_1fCqUO7AAPHsZTkz_iVX1NfuYQsn0LHgCCiOsSzhLiP4Ho7VynSf_ceJJw&upload_protocol=resumable, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mybucket/o/user%2FNyq7dMqe1kcAZ77R1YwH5fsAkV83%2Fcontent%2F43aa2d41-7a19-11ec-bd39-8508fcd9d025-low_res?uploadType=resumable&name=user%2FNyq7dMqe1kcAZ77R1YwH5fsAkV83%2Fposts%2F43aa2d41-7a19-11ec-bd39-8508f&upload_id=ADPycdv0-OYZPx3zAGzLrn25ZdI9srgkgABHGKb_1fCqUO7AAPHsZTkz_iVX1NfuYQsn0LHgCCiOsSzhLiP4Ho7VynSf_ceJJw&upload_protocol=resumable}
```

This result in a `[firebase_storage/unknown] An unknown error occurred, please check the server response.`
But this time i can see the iOS failure, not the server response unfortunately...

So what does `Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1017 "cannot parse response"` mean and how to fix it please ?

**Note** : I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820224/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1017-cannot-parse-response) but it's not really something i can fix myself as i am using the Firebase iOS SDK...

EDIT :

I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/9250) and a case in Firebase Support to get more information about this as no one seem to have some for now unfortunately.
This is probably a bug server-side as i can't reproduce it 100% of the time and the error is also not useful for debug.

EDIT 2 :

Firebase support was able to reproduce this issue with quite low internet connections, but in my case this happens also with normal connectivity.
I have also set the `metadata` specifying the `content-type` to avoid an extra "parsing" server side but it didn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: seems there is a problem with the request and response - such as json format when its expecting something else.

Comment: That's also my guess, but i am simply using `uploadFile` method so i have no customization / error prone code related to json input as it is probably done by the Firebase SDK itself :/

Comment: @Tom3652 do you got solution?

Comment: I am still in touch with Firebase support, they insisted on setting the metadata on the file upload but i am still having the issue. Feel free to comment out the issue i have mentioned or also raise a case to Firebase support, this may help indicate that this is a real issue :/

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem.
But I got it why occured this problem.
Maybe,this problem is occured by weakly network level.
If you want to reproduce this problem,Please Use "Network Link Conditioner.prefPane" in "Hardware" of "Additional tools for Xcode"
[Additional tools for Xcode Download link](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Network)

I could reproduce below settings.

```
Downlink Bandwidth: 10 Kbps
Downlink Packets Dropped: 5 %
Downlink Delay: 440 ms

Uplink Bandwidth: 10 Kbps
Uplink Packets Dropped: 5 %
Uplink Delay: 440 ms

DNS Delay: NO SET VALUE
```

It setting could add by manage profiles.
Good Luck, and I apporogy my English.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however this should be fixed by Firebase itself, this is not something i did wrong i know it now.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your header values as well. If headers contain empty values, that could also be a reason for getting the parsing error (NSURLErrorDomain with code -1017).

Ensure that all the headers you're adding to your URLRequest have valid non-empty values. An empty or improperly formatted header could cause issues when the request is sent and the response is received. This could lead to a parsing error, especially if the server is expecting specific header values or formats.

Double-check the values being added using addValue(_:forHTTPHeaderField:) to make sure they are correctly populated with the necessary information, such as the correct content type, authorization token, or any other header fields your API might require.

Additionally, verify the server's expected response format and ensure that your code properly handles this format when receiving and parsing the response data.

This error can often arise due to various factors, so reviewing both the headers and the response handling process is essential to pinpoint and resolve the issue.