# Safari "Cannot parse response NSURLErrorDomain:-1017" on Google Cloud Storage hosted image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, safari

I have looked at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/937253/https-doesnt-work-with-safari?_gl=1*xcld45*_ga*MjAyNzAyMTgwNC4xNjU2NDk0MjU0*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY4MzAyNTkyNC4xMDAuMC4xNjgzMDI1OTI0LjAuMC4w), [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7430493) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820224/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1017-cannot-parse-response) link, none helped.

I have some images hosted in a GCP bucket. When trying to access the image through the public url, it works in every browser, except for Safari.

Safari gives this error: `Cannot parse response: NSURLErrorDomain:-1017.`

I tried both fetching the image with an http request, and accessing directly by clicking on the link, both fail with the same error.

If I reupload the image to the bucket, and add the same custom headers, it works fine, but this has been happening for some customers when they upload their content, so it's pretty annoying.

I have some large headers, so I have considered that maybe they were *too* big, but it was not the case, since I have asserted that reuploading the image with the same headers works no problem.